# Worldclim: getData() in R (latitude/longitude coordinates): Error in utils::unzip(zipfile, exdir = dirname(zipfile)) : 'exdir' does not exist

Tags: r, directory, latitude-longitude, raster

**Uploading longitude and latitude coordinates in a .csv file using getData():**

I am sorry for asking such a basic question but I am new to R, and I am having trouble uploading my .csv file containing latitude and longitude coordinates using the function getData(). The idea is to upload the data in worldlcim.

The code I used was:

```
bioclim.data <- getData(name = "worldclim",
                    var = "bio",
                    res = 2.5,
                    path "~/Documents/TerneyProposal/UpalPublishedPapers/Blue_Whale_Paper/Data_Blue_Whale_Project/Blue_Whale_GPS_CSV.csv")enter code here
```

However, I keep on getting this error message:

```
trying URL 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/grid/cur/bio_2-5m_bil.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 129319755 bytes (123.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 123.3 MB


 Could not download file -- perhaps it does not exist
Error in utils::unzip(zipfile, exdir = dirname(zipfile)) : 
 'exdir' does not exist
```

I don't understand this message because my .csv file is not in a zip file, and this file also opens easily when I use the function read.csv("data")

Very kind regards if anyone could please kindly advise?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! These kinds of errors are a bit misleading... I think the main issue is probably that your file is not in the folder it expects. Run:

```
getwd()
```

to see what the working folder is... **that** is where it's expecting the file. Either move the file into that folder, or you can change your session's working directory to the folder where the file is, by writing:

```
setwd("pathToYourFile")
```

If you're on windows, remember to change those pesky `\` to `/`.

Give it a try!

Comment: Hi Amit! Thank you for getting back to me so swiftly. I am using the same directory to open the data using read.csv("data") without a problem. I think the problem might be something else or it is the way I have typed the directory in the code. I feel very confused! Do you have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I see. Does your working directory have write access? Can you run the examples on https://cmerow.github.io/RDataScience/05_Raster.html#5_worldclim?

Comment: Hi Amit! The data I am trying to upload is my own, but I cannot put it publicly online; however, I would be willing to send it via email. I had no problem uploading the examples in that link you sent me. In fact, thank you! This will be really helpful for the rest of my project. I still cannot upload my data into the  bioclim model (above). Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: I have no problem opening my data using using the same directory  Blue.whale<-read.csv("~/Documents/TerneyProposal/UpalPublishedPapers/Blue_Whale_Paper/Data_Blue_Whale_Project/Blue_Whale_GPS_Best.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

Comment: This is exactly the same directory that is incorporated into the model bioclim.data that I am trying to open

Comment: sure... email me: mexindian@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks Amit! I sent you an email.